# iTextPdf set fields of xfa form

Tags: java, pdf, itextpdf, xfa

It's been many days that im trying to figure out how to set the values of fields in a PDF XFA form. I managed to do it using fill xfa.fillXfaForm() where I pass an input stream to my xml file containing the dataset. However i found that not all fields in the xfa form are shown in the dataset whenever I print the xfa. I am wondering how would I be able to set the value of those xfa fields that do not appear in the dataset. At the moment I can only set the values of those that are available in the dataset.

Thanks

Comment: The question isn't clear. Please feed your form to our demo: http://demo.itextsupport.com/xfademo/uploadpdf.jsp Then provide feedback explaining which fields are missing. By doing this, you send us the form for us to take a look at it.

Comment: Hi Bruno, I uploaded the pdf using that link. Just like what my current issue is, the PDF has more fields than what appears in the <form> section